# Matching innerHTML Contents using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a card matching game. I have it set up to change bg color to green when I click on the box. How do I have it check the contents of the second card (Which will also turn green) and if they are a match, make them invisible?

```
        <style type="text/css">
        .box {
                background-color: black;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                margin: 10px;
                line-height: 100px;
                color:white;
                font-size: 48;
                font-family: helvetica;
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
             }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">Bacon</div>
    <div class="box">Waffle</div>
    <div class="box">Toast</div> <br>

    <div class="box">Coffee</div>
    <div class="box">Eggs</div>
    <div class="box">Oatmeal</div> <br>

    <div class="box">Eggs</div>
    <div class="box">Toast</div>
    <div class="box">pancakes</div><br>

    <div class="box">Waffle</div>
    <div class="box">Oatmeal</div>
    <div class="box">Bacon</div><br>


    <script type="text/javascript">   
       var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
            for (var i=0; i< boxes.length; i++){
                boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
            }
           boxes[0].onclick = function(){
                boxes[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";    
           }
       boxes[1].onclick = function(){
                boxes[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
           boxes[2].onclick = function(){
                boxes[2].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[3].onclick = function(){
                boxes[3].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[4].onclick = function(){
                boxes[4].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[5].onclick = function(){
                boxes[5].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[6].onclick = function(){
                boxes[6].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[7].onclick = function(){
                boxes[7].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
           boxes[8].onclick = function(){
                boxes[8].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[9].onclick = function(){
                boxes[9].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[10].onclick = function(){
                boxes[10].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[11].onclick = function(){
                boxes[11].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
```

Comment: It will require that you store what was clicked first and compare that value with what was clicked second.

Comment: **How do I have it check the contents of the second card** what does this mean?

Comment: @kurt you mean, on first click they will have a green background, and on the second click they will become invisible. Right?

Comment: @Ayan If they actually match, yes.

Answer (score 1):

*No jquery, Just pure JS*

First we iterate and

- `boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";` Assign the bg color to black.
- `boxes[i].onclick = clickFN;` and attach a callback function.

**Callback FN**

```js
function clickFN() {
  var elem = this,
    style = elem.style;
  if (lastClickedElem && elem === lastClickedElem) {
    style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  style.backgroundColor = "green";
  lastClickedElem = elem;
}
```

First `this` gives the reference to the interacted element.

- Check if any lastClickedElem exists or not.`lastClickedElem && elem === lastClickedElem`
- If exists, and its the same element hide it.`style.visibility = 'hidden';`
- Sets the bg color to green.
- Update the lastClickedElem variable.

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box'),
  lastClickedElem;
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
  // attach the callback for the click interaction.
  boxes[i].onclick = clickFN;
}
// callback function for the click event.
function clickFN() {
  var elem = this,
    style = elem.style;
  if (lastClickedElem && elem === lastClickedElem) {
    style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  style.backgroundColor = "green";
  lastClickedElem = elem;
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 48;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Bacon</div>
<div class="box">Waffle</div>
<div class="box">Toast</div>
<br>

<div class="box">Coffee</div>
<div class="box">Eggs</div>
<div class="box">Oatmeal</div>
<br>

<div class="box">Eggs</div>
<div class="box">Toast</div>
<div class="box">pancakes</div>
<br>

<div class="box">Waffle</div>
<div class="box">Oatmeal</div>
<div class="box">Bacon</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Hey @Adjit please check. Have added some explanation.

Comment: hey @kurt let me know if this was the one you were looking for or we can have improvements!

Comment: It does not work... If you click on a box that does not match the previous clicked element, you should deselect the previous one... Moreover if you click twice on the same box, the box should not disappear...

Comment: Oh I got it wrong way then. Thanks @R.Foubert , will update soon.

Comment: This is definitely an awesome start! Like @R.Foubert said though, resetting on wrong selection would be ideal. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @R.Foubert and kurt Have updated the code and fixed the bug... Yayyy!!!! Thanks guys... Let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that :

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

// remeber the last box clicked
var _lastClicked = null;

for (var i=0; i< boxes.length; i++){
  boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
  boxes[i].addEventListener('click', onBox_click);
}

function onBox_click(domEvent){
  // clicked element
  var clicked = domEvent.target;
  
  // prevent clicking on the same element
  if (_lastClicked && _lastClicked === clicked)
    return;
  
  // if there is a box clicked and if the value match
  if (_lastClicked && clicked.innerHTML === _lastClicked.innerHTML){
    // the two boxes should disappear and we reset last clicked
    _lastClicked.style.opacity = 0;
    clicked.style.opacity = 0;
    _lastClicked = null;
  }
  
  // if there is a box clicked and if the value does not match 
  if (_lastClicked && clicked.innerHTML !== _lastClicked.innerHTML){
    // reset the color of the last clicked to black
    _lastClicked.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
  
  _lastClicked = clicked;
  clicked.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color:white;
  font-size: 48;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Bacon</div>
<div class="box">Waffle</div>
<div class="box">Toast</div> <br>

<div class="box">Coffee</div>
<div class="box">Eggs</div>
<div class="box">Oatmeal</div> <br>

<div class="box">Eggs</div>
<div class="box">Toast</div>
<div class="box">pancakes</div><br>

<div class="box">Waffle</div>
<div class="box">Oatmeal</div>
<div class="box">Bacon</div><br>
```

I get rid of all your useless lines of code to listen clicks on the boxes. It's now easier to use.

Basically I just remember in the _lastClicked variable the last boxes clicked and I compare it to the new box clicked. If it matches I make them disappear and I reset the _lastClicked variable. If it does not match I reset the _lastClicked's background color to black.

I hope it helps ;)

PS: I also make sure the element clicked is not the same as before. If you don't do that, clicking twice on the same element will make it disappear :p

Comment: I did not change a lot of things... But yes maybe I completed his homework... :p However I explained everything so if he wants to understand... ^^

Answer (score 0):

This seemed fun, I came up with this to get you started. You still have some logic to figure out, I always store the last one clicked, where I imagine you want to reset on wrong selection.

Also, I used jquery for ease.

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
            for (var i=0; i< boxes.length; i++){
                boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
            }
           boxes[0].onclick = function(){
                boxes[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";    
           }
       boxes[1].onclick = function(){
                boxes[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
           boxes[2].onclick = function(){
                boxes[2].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[3].onclick = function(){
                boxes[3].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[4].onclick = function(){
                boxes[4].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[5].onclick = function(){
                boxes[5].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[6].onclick = function(){
                boxes[6].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[7].onclick = function(){
                boxes[7].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
           boxes[8].onclick = function(){
                boxes[8].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[9].onclick = function(){
                boxes[9].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[10].onclick = function(){
                boxes[10].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
            boxes[11].onclick = function(){
                boxes[11].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
          
var lastSelected;
$('.box').click(function(){
   if(lastSelected && $(lastSelected).text() === $(this).text()){
     console.log('Match')
     $(lastSelected).addClass('hidden');
     $(this).addClass('hidden');
   }
  lastSelected = $(this);
});
```

```css
.box {
                background-color: black;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                margin: 10px;
                line-height: 100px;
                color:white;
                font-size: 48;
                font-family: helvetica;
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
             }

.hidden{
      visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Bacon</div>
    <div class="box">Waffle</div>
    <div class="box">Toast</div> <br>

    <div class="box">Coffee</div>
    <div class="box">Eggs</div>
    <div class="box">Oatmeal</div> <br>

    <div class="box">Eggs</div>
    <div class="box">Toast</div>
    <div class="box">pancakes</div><br>

    <div class="box">Waffle</div>
    <div class="box">Oatmeal</div>
    <div class="box">Bacon</div><br>
```